# Sample Kafka code in J2ee and Jboss/Wildfly Application Server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to use Kafka service with Jakarta ee technology and Jboss/Wildfly server application to manage large volume of messages. Can anyone suggest a sample code for this? Or a document that explains this in detail

Comment: Does this help http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/apache-kafka/getting-started-with-apache-kafka-and-wildfly/?

Comment: Take a look at [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io)